# Convergence of characteristic functions for random vectors: references?

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\ (Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ two *independent* sequences of real random variables.
Suppose $X_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{d}X,$ $Y_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{d}Y$.
Then I'm quite sure that $(X_n,Y_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{d}(X,Y)$.

The proof I've in mind uses the characteristic functions for 1 and 2 variables $\Phi_X(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$, $\Phi_{(X,Y)}(s,t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{i(sX+tY)}]$.
The ingredients are the following:

$\bullet\ X_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{d}X \iff \Phi_{X_n}(t)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\Phi_X(t)\ \forall t\in\mathbb{R}$

$\bullet\ \Phi_{(X_n,Y_n)}(s,t)=\Phi_{X_n}(s)\,\Phi_{Y_n}(t)$, thanks to independence

$\bullet\ (X_n,Y_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{d}(X,Y) \iff \Phi_{(X_n,Y_n)}(s,t)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\Phi_{(X,Y)}(s,t)\ \forall s,t\in\mathbb{R}$

I'm looking for a reference: I found many for the 1st point, the 2nd point is very easy, but I didn't found anywhere the 3rd statement. Can you help me?

Comment: If it makes you feel happier, the proof you have in mind is correct.

Comment: OK thank you :D But I'ma still looking for a reference

Comment: you can reference my quote here :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reference is theorem 29.4 in Billingsley's "[Probability and Measure](http://books.google.com/books?id=z39jQgAACAAJ)" book (p.383 of the 1995 third edition). It deals with Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: £10 says  you didn't memorise that reference page off the top of your head :P

Comment: @Lost1 Everyone should have Billingsley's book at arm's reach :P!

Comment: I found that book, thank you!